# Intellij IDEA community edition - support for maven properties

Tags: properties, maven, intellij-idea

While using IDEA community edition, local maven custom properties are shown as errors in my pom.xml...

e.g.

```
<!-- bar/pom.xml -->

<properties>
    <foo.version>1.0.0</foo.version>
    ...
</properties>
...
...
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>blah.bar</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo-core</artifactId>
            <version>${foo.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

**${foo.version}** is show in red as an error "Dependency... ${foo.version} not found..."

it appears that IDEA is not resolving the property...

nb: foo-core-1.0.0 (pom/jar) is available in my local repo

any ideas?

Comment: Is it compiled ok? Does cursor jump to <foo.version>1.0.0</foo.version>, when ctrl+click on ${foo.version} ?

Comment: It seems like it works in a single project but if you depend on a submodule of another project it doesn't work.

Comment: @Timofei no, ctrl+click on ${foo.version} doesn't jump to property definition at <foo.version>1.0.0</foo.version>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a commonly reported issue: [http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA?q=maven+properties+red](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA?q=maven%20properties%20red)

I also have the same issue with RC 2